# Options for defining preprocessor macros with parameters for entire project or solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros, c-preprocessor

I want some macros having parameters to be available in all files in a project or better a complete solution. In VS2010, if I add them to the Preprocessor Definitions in properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor using something like

```
SQUARE(x)=((x)*(x));CUBE(x)=(SQUARE(x)*x);
```

the macro definitions are not used by the compiler. However the approach may be close since IntelliSense provides the correct definitions when I hover over the macros in the source code.

Is there a way to define the macros and make them visible without including a header with their definitions in every file?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I think in the project properties you can only define preprocessor variables but not functions (only what's allowed for [compiler parameter -D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx)) . To make preproc function available for whole project without including header everywhere, you could include the header in "stdafx.h", which normally is already included in all .cpp files.

Comment: Use headers like the language intends you to do it.  You'll thank yourself later.  (Or maybe the next developer will anyway...)

Comment: The source code could use a good cleaning up. In fact, the macros I would like to make visible in the entire project work together to output "FIXMEs" during a build that have the file name and line number formatted so that they can be clicked to get to the right location for the issue. There are many files, as in hundreds. That too should be addressed, but one thing at a time. For now, it would be a disruptive and  time-consuming effort to add the macros to a header and the include that header in each of the header and source files. Currently there is no universal header where they can be put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the macro in a file and automatically include it into all files using the /FI option:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx

Syntax: /FI[ ]pathname

The /FI option has the same effect as including the file at top of every source file.

Comment: Thank you! The /FI option is exactly what I had wanted.